# Connecting Spring applicaion with Postgres database inside a docker container

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a remote server on which is installed docker and i'm trying to CI/CD a spring-boot application and a database on it. However for some reason it seems that i cannot connect my springboot application to the database. Both are running in seperate containers and are in the same network. I also made sure that the port is correct to connect to the database. The user for the database is also correct in the spring-boot application.

Here is the error message:

```
Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  app:
      image: cr.gitlab.fhnw.ch/ip34-23vt/ip34-23vt_therewrite/therewrite/frontend:latest
      restart: always
      ports:
          - "8080:80"
      networks:
        - therewrite
  database:
      container_name: postgresCont
      image: postgres:latest
      environment:
        POSTGRES_USER: postgres
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin
        POSTGRES_DB: TheRewrite
      volumes:
        - /var/lib/docker/volumes/postgres-volume/_data
      ports:
        - '5432:5432'
      expose:
        - '5432'
      networks:
        - therewrite
networks:
  therewrite:
    name: therewrite
    external: true
    driver: bridge
```

Here are my sping-boot properties:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB
# node app url:
app.url=http://localhost:3000
app.access=/pdf/list,/pdf/get/*,/file/upload,/annotation/**
# database connection:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TheRewrite
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=admin

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My containers look like this:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                                                         COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                         PORTS                                       NAMES
7732b3aa8d36   cr.gitlab.fhnw.ch/ip34-23vt/ip34-23vt_therewrite/therewrite/frontend:latest   "java -jar /app.jar"     8 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 7 seconds ago                                               therewrite-app-1
8a1d5d3d4508   postgres:latest                                                               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes                   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp, :::5432->5432/tcp   postgresCont
```

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually refers to the current container.  You need to use the Compose service name `database` as a host name for connections between containers.  I'd set this Compose-environment-specific setup in a `environment: { SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: ... }` variable, rather than embedding it into your application's jar file.